# How to edit httptrigger function.json file for the project uploaded by VSCode

Tags: azure, azure-http-trigger

I use vscode extension
[Azure Functions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions) to create htmltrigger project on my local.

and I want to edit htmltrigger `authLevel` to `anonymous`, but I searched my local vscode folder for `function.json` and not found it
[image]

and azure portal show `Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting.`, it can not edit function.json
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the function.json file is generated after VS build. Check whether it's in a folder named after your function, under ~\bin....... folder.

Comment: thanks, but I edited bin\function.json anonymous authLevel and deploy again, system auto-generate function authLevel not function authLevel..

Comment: you need to deploy the one in the bin folder

Comment: thanks, it have to deploy by CLI, and it can't use vscode extension default botton.